# Convert template C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, type-conversion

i have template in project c++ and i want to translate code to c# now, and i get some errors in template c#.

In C++

```
    template<typename T>
struct pares
{
    DWORD64 first;
    T* second;
};
template<typename T>
struct hash_node
{
    pares<T> mValue;
    hash_node<T>* mpNext;
};

template<typename T>
struct hashtable
{
    DWORD64 vtable;
    hash_node<T>** mpBucketArray;
    unsigned int mnBucketCount;
    unsigned int mnElementCount;
    //...
};

template<typename T>
struct hashtable_iterator
{
    hash_node<T>* mpNode;
    hash_node<T>** mpBucket;
};
```

In C#

```
    public class pair<T>
{
    public Int64 first;
    public T second;
}

public class hash_node<T> 
{
    public pair<T> mValue = new pair<T>();
    public hash_node<T> mpNext;
}


public class hashtable<T>
{
    public Int64 vtable;
    public hash_node<T>[] mpBucketArray;
    public int mnBucketCount;
    public int mnElementCount;

}
public class hashtable_iterator<T>
{
    public hash_node<T> mpNode;
    public hash_node<T> mpBucket;
}
```

Inside a function in c++ project i have this line , its fine without error:

```
hashtable<DWORD64>* table = (hashtable<DWORD64>*)(pObfuscationMgr + 8);
```

But in C# get error:

> Cannot convert type 'long' to 'hashtable'

```
 hashtable<Int64> table =  (hashtable<Int64>)(pObfuscationMgr + 8);
```

Comment: What do you think that error means?

Comment: that canot convert type, but type already correct, Int64

Comment: What is `pObfuscationMgr` (in both languages)?

Comment: Converting C++ code that heavily uses templates and unsafe/unchecked casts like that to C# is likely to be pretty fraught - there are almost certainly more appropriate ways of achieving the same thing. How much code is it?

Comment: pObfuscationMgr  is a int64 type, code is no much big 284 lines

Comment: You have to understand that `template` and `generic` are two very different things even though the syntax seems somewhat similar. So don't try to do a verbatim translation but try to find how you would achieve that functionality in C# mainly from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are telling the compiler to interpret a memory position as a `hashtable<>` object. This works in C++ because you have the tool to do that: pointers. A pointer is just a memory position with an associated type.

You have a memory block pointed by `pObfuscationMgr`, and you intend to create a pointer to a `hashtable<>` and this way understand the contents at that memory position (plus eight) as a `hashtable<>`.

If you do a verbatim translation to C#:

```
hashtable<Int64> table =  (hashtable<Int64>)(pObfuscationMgr + 8);
```

Pointers are lost in that translation, because there are no pointers in C#. So, now `pObfuscationMgr` is now just a `long`, and hence the compiler's error: you cannot transform a `long` into a `hashtable<>`.

For example, you can do this in C or C++:

```
void foo()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int * ptr1 = (int *) &buffer;
    int * ptr2 = (int *) ( &buffer + 8 );


    *ptr1 = 40;
    *ptr1 += 2;

    *ptr2 = 5;
    *ptr2 *= 2;

    printf( "%d\n", *ptr1 ); 
    printf( "%d\n", *ptr2 ); 
}
```

In the code above, you are creating a buffering area in the stack, in the shape of a `char` array. Then you create the `ptr1` and `ptr2` pointers, and make them point to the beginning of that area and to the beginning of that area plus eight. Then you can manage both pointers as if they were pointing to real variables. That is more or less similar to what the original code does.

You won't be successful by doing a verbatim translation of C++ code into C#. Of course that translation is achievable, but having a deep knowledge about memory in C++ and how to represent that in C#, i.e., doing a real translation.

Hope this (somehow) helps.